# django-rest-framework raises an error in a model when accessing another model with a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one referring the other one:

```
class RatesTable(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='rates_tables', verbose_name=_('Hotel'))
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, related_name='rates_tables', verbose_name=_('Contract'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Description'))
    is_base = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Is a base rate-table?'))
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Start Date'))
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Due Date'))
    release = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Release'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Rates Table')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Rates Tables')
        unique_together = ('contract', 'start_date', 'due_date')
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['hotel',]),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}][{}]{} {} {}-{}".format(self.id, self.hotel.name, self.contract.id, self.name, self.start_date, self.due_date)

class Rate(models.Model):
    rates_table = models.ForeignKey(RatesTable, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='rates', verbose_name=_('Rates Table'))
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='product_rates', verbose_name=_('Product'))
    rate = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Rate'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Rate')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Rates')
        unique_together = ('rates_table', 'product')

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}][{}][{}]{}".format(self.id, self.rates_table.contract, self.rates_table.id, self.product.name)
```

Each one has its own standard end-point in `urls.py`. End-point for model `RatesTable` works perfectly, but end-point for model `Rate` raises this error: `return "[{}][{}]{} {} {}-{}".format(self.id, self.hotel.name, self.contract.id, self.name, self.start_date, self.due_date)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`, and this error is raised on method `__str__(self)` of model `RatesTable`, not model `Rate`!

I don't know why DRF raises an error in the referenced model. It's the only case it happens, and I have many models with foreign keys

Comment: your `self.rates_table` relation may be `None`

Comment: Nope, it is not the case. I don't have any record with a null value in the foreign key column.

Comment: You'd defined `contract` as `null=True`, ***it may be the issue***

Comment: @JPG You are right!!! it was so.